# spread operator is not working in react as {...this.state.attributes}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spread-syntax

I am facing issue unexpected token this as ...this is not working as attribute in React.

```
<button {...this.state.attributes}> Save </button>
```

this has value in this scope.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Shraddha Agrawal

Comment: there must be three dots :-P,can you please share what attributes contains

Answer (score 1):

Might be even a typo ...this and not ..this. See below.

```
        import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import logo from './logo.svg';
        import './App.css';

        class App extends Component {

          state = {className:"button", style:{color: 'red'}}

          render() {
            return (
              <div>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                <button {...this.state}>Hello World</button>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }

        export default App;
```

Comment: sorry its ...this only